# Performing K mean clustering to multiple set of data in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, error-handling, split, k-means

I have got five different types of data with multiple columns. I want to perform a k means clustering on the data set but I keep getting the below response after concatenating the whole data set together.

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6E24H.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aamfj.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcWHo.png)

Kindly let me know if I am doing something wrong. I would appreciate any help I can get right now. Thanks

[Python code link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16qkhz96wjoEXOIFXxAXYaxKPOmJcJvSM/view?usp=sharing)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import plotly.express as px
```

#Read Temperature Data

Cap_80=pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\User\Documents\CapacitorEXP\Temp_Cap_2200\data0203_200uf_80deg.csv",encoding='unicode_escape')

Cap_90=pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\User\Documents\CapacitorEXP\Temp_Cap_2200\data0303_2200uf_90deg.csv",encoding='unicode_escape')

Cap_100=pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\User\Documents\CapacitorEXP\Temp_Cap_2200\data0803_200uf_110deg.csv",encoding='unicode_escape')

Cap_110=pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\User\Documents\CapacitorEXP\Temp_Cap_2200\data0803_2200uf_110deg.csv",encoding='unicode_escape')

Cap_120=pd.read_csv(r"C:UsersUserDocumentsCapacitorEXPTemp_Cap_2200data1803_2200uf_120deg.csv",cap_120encoding='unicode_escape')

```
#Locate column in each dataset
df1 = pd.DataFrame(Cap_80.iloc[:,5:9].reset_index(drop=True))
                   
df2 = pd.DataFrame(Cap_90.iloc[:,5:9].reset_index(drop=True))

df3 = pd.DataFrame(Cap_100.iloc[:,5:9].reset_index(drop=True))

df4 = pd.DataFrame(Cap_110.iloc[:,5:9].reset_index(drop=True))
                   
df5 = pd.DataFrame(Cap_120.iloc[:,5:9].reset_index(drop=True))

#Merge all dataset together
df = (df1, df2, df3, df4, df5)
data = pd.concat(df)

#Finding the number of k using the elbow method
wcss=[]
for i in range(1,7):
kmeans = KMeans(i)
kmeans.fit(data)
wcss_iter = kmeans.inertia_
wcss.append(wcss_iter)

number_clusters = range(1,7)
plt.plot(number_clusters,wcss)
plt.title('The Elbow title')
plt.xlabel('Number of clusters')
plt.ylabel('WCSS')

k_means_optimum = KMeans(n_clusters = 2, init = 'k-means++',  random_state=42)
y = k_means_optimum.fit_predict(data)
print(y)
```

Comment: Please see if you can include the content of the script you are running in the question here. There is part that calls the `split` function that it is complaining about.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have just updated the question with the code. thanks

Comment: Don't copy your code as a link. Show it in the question directly please.

Comment: Okay i will do that now